Where does NSD software store DNS Records for hostnames and IP addresses in Ubuntu?
I'm trying to find out which config file holds our internal network's A Records and PTR Records for our internal hostnames. Our company uses NSD for the authoritative name servers and the servers are Ubuntu.
I have access to our authoritative name server machines and have tried to check the files in /etc/nsd/zones. I can see the records for the mappings between internal domain names and VIPs. However, I cannot find the record for the mappings between hostnames and IP addresses and yet every hostname and IP address can be resolved. For example, from my workstation, when I do
host hostname1.company.com

it outputs
hostname1.company.com has address 10.1.2.3

or when I do
host 10.1.2.3

it outputs
98.76.54.32.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer hostname1.company.com.

but I cannot find hostname1.company.com nor 10.1.2.3 in the files inside /etc/nsd/zones in our authoritative name server machines.
We do not use any other authoritative name server software than NSD, so it can't be that those missing A Records and PTR records for hostnames and IP addresses are in other software config.
Do the files in /etc/nsd/zones only contain records for mappings between internal domain name and VIPs? Where are the records for the mappings between internal hostnames and IP address located?

why not ask them? https://lists.nlnetlabs.nl/mailman/listinfo/nsd-users  hardly anyone here will use this :)
